# Problem with particles, converted into mesh objects

Tags: modeling, particles, conversion

I have an object with a particle system.
The particle system emits another object as a hair.
I use "Convert" button in modifers tab in order to turn the "particles" into simple mesh objects.

But then I face the **problem**:
It seems like those converted particles-objects, are still connected to each other somehow. So If I select one object and go to edit mode - all of them goes to edit mode. And if I change one of them in edit mode, all of them will be changed. I also can't join them into one object.

Why id it happening, and how I can disconnect them and get simple mesh objects?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Object Mode* select all your objects. Press <kbd>U</kbd> and unlink the object and the data to make single user objects.