# UNLINK does not work to convert particles into new/original meshes

Tags: mesh, particles, conversion

I am converting a particle system (based on a collection of meshes) into new meshes.

The 'new' meshes stay connected (as I can see in EDIT mode) to the original one. Setting every single mesh to an 'original' mesh in the object tab takes a lot of time.

This question... [Problem with particles, converted into mesh objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72543/problem-with-particles-converted-into-mesh-objects)
...seems to be the same, but the answer which is UNLINK(ING) the object(s) by pressing 'U' makes everything disappear as if I am hitting a delete button instead of 'unlink'.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-can-i-convert-a-hair-particle-system-into-3d-editable-objects

Comment: Actually these answers from previous questions don't work with my project. I adjusted my question a to explain it.

Comment: Hard to say without more information.. Which Blender version? What do you choose to unlink in U menu? How do objects look like before you unlink, where are their origin points, can you post a screenshot? In 2.79 latest builds unlinking works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on this page: [Can not find unlink object data in Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128760/can-not-find-unlink-object-data-in-blender-2-8)

In Short: *Go to Object Menu --> Relations --> Make Single User.*

'Unlink' doesn't seem to work anymore in Blender 2.8. Things disappear when I unlink.